# My laptop says I'm using around 10% CPU but it's running at 1.9GHz (i7 q720 rated at 1.6GHZ) constantly

Tags: laptop, cpu, overheating

My laptop seems to be running really quick when technically it's not doing anything. The fan is always on full and although it hasn't got any stability issues. I can't help thinking something's wrong.

It runs very hot, around 75 degrees too.
I have very few applications open and as I said, my CPU is barely being utilised, it's just doing nothing, really quickly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

- Computer specs: Intel i7 Q720 @1.6GHz
- 16GB Corsair Vengeance RAM
- ATI  mobility Radeon HD5650
- OCZ Agility 2 24GB SSD
- 640GB HDD
- External BenQ    27" monitor

Comment: Sounds perfectly normal to me, an i7 needs a fan even if it does nothing it is doing something . . . producing heat, thus the fan. The heat youor system is subjected to always plays a role too, live in jamaica or australia?

Comment: Is the CPU fan running all the time of the fan for cooling the laptop (which includes the CPU **and other heat sources**). Also, as previously said, a CPU idling still produces some heat.

Answer (score 3):

A few points of interest:

1. Your processor will *always* run at 1.9GHz, unless you're utilizing some form of power saving technology.  Have you looked at your power management settings to see if they are "always on, all the time?"
2. Your fan being always on may not mean anything; processors still produce heat, even when they are idling (running in a wait loop).  Again, I would check your power management settings.

How long you've owned this laptop is relevant also. If it has always behaved this way, it may be the way it is designed to work.  If it suddenly started happening, after a lengthy period of running at 40 degrees C, I might be concerned.